# how to change the color of the icon to white on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, webkit

I've the following `div`

```html
<div class="box-decoration">
             <a href="dashboardme.html"><img src="..\change\icons\pdf.png"> Owner-Operator Profile
             </a>
</div>
```

I want to change the color of the `pdf` icon into white (as in screenshot), and before hover it looks blue.
How can I change the color of the icon on `hover` that looks something like this[image]

Comment: you can't change color of image no hover, you need to sprite image for that or used font icon...

Comment: how to use font-icon , to achieve the above ? @ManishPatel

Comment: You can used Font Awesome icons...https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
.box-decoration:hover img{
   filter: brightness(0) invert(1);  
}
```

Comment: Yeah that works for me,, can you please explain what this invert(1) means?

Comment: brightness(0)  give you a completely image black output. Then, invert(1) it will change its image from black to white. See [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-filter-effects-blur-grayscale-brightness-and-more-in-css/)